# Classic ASP InStr() Evaluates True on Empty Comparison String

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I ran into an issue with the Classic ASP VbScript `InStr()` function.  As shown below, the second call to `InStr()` returns `1` when searching for an empty string in a non empty string.  I'm curious why this is happening.

```
' InStr Test
Dim someText : someText = "So say we all"
Dim emptyString : emptyString = ""

'' I expect this to be true
If inStr(1,someText,"so",1) > 0 Then
    Response.write ( "I found ""so""<br />" )
End If 

'' I expect this to be false
If inStr(1, someText, emptyString, 1) > 0 Then
    Response.Write( "I found an empty string<br />" )
End If
```

**EDIT:**
Some additional clarification:  The reason for the question came up when debugging legacy code and running into a situation like this:

```
Function Go(value)
     If InStr(1, "Option1|Option2|Option3", value, 1) > 0 Then
          ' Do some stuff
     End If
End Function
```

In some cases function `Go()` can get called with an empty string.  The original developer's intent was not to check whether `value` was empty, but rather, whether or not `value` was equal to one of the piped delimited values (Option1,Option2, etc.).

Thinking about this further it makes sense that every string is created from an empty string, and I can understand why a programming language would assume a string with all characters removed still contains the empty string.

What doesn't make sense to me is why programming languages are implementing this.  Consider these 2 statements:

```
InStr("so say we all", "s") '' evaluates to 1
InStr("so say we all", "")  '' evaluates to 1
```

The `InStr()` function will return the position of the first occurrence of one string within another. In both of the above cases, the result is 1.  However, position 1 always contains the character "s", not an empty string.  Furthermore, using another string function like Len() or LenB() on an empty string alone will result in 0, indicating a character length of 0.

It seems that there is some inconsistency here.  The empty string contained in all strings is not actually a character, but the InStr() function is treating it as one when other string functions are not.  I find this to be un-intuitive and un-necessary.

Comment: If that `Go()` function is supposed to detect whether `value` is one of the given options, it's seriously badly coded. Right now, it'll return True for all sorts of things that aren't one of the options, like "opt", or "ion", or --as you've discovered-- an empty string. In other words, it's not misbehaving when given an empty string because `InStr()` is somehow designed wrong, but because it failed to account for all the possible inputs.

Comment: I agree on the bad design for this function.  As I said, this is legacy code I stumbled upon and had to deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Empty String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_string) is the [Identity Element](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IdentityElement.html) for Strings:

> The identity element I (also denoted E, e, or 1) of a group or related
>   mathematical structure S is the unique element such that Ia=aI=a for
>   every element a in S. The symbol "E" derives from the German word for
>   unity, "Einheit." An identity element is also called a unit element.

If you add 0 to a number n the result is n; if you add/concatenate "" to a string s the result is s:

```
>> WScript.Echo CStr(1 = 1 + 0)
>> WScript.Echo CStr("a" = "a" & "")
>>
True
True
```

So every String and SubString contains at least one "":

```
>> s = "abc"
>> For p = 1 To Len(s)
>>     WScript.Echo InStr(p, s, "")
>> Next
>>
1
2
3
```

and [Instr()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) reports that faithfully. The docs even state:

```
InStr([start, ]string1, string2[, compare])
...
The InStr function returns the following values:
...
string2 is zero-length            start
```

WRT your

> However, position 1 always contains the character "s", not an empty
>   string.

==>

> Position 1 always contains the character "s", and therefore an empty
>   string too.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  Since an empty string is not actually a character, would it not be more helpful to a programmer to treat empty strings similar to null, as in, a string is either null, empty, or neither? I see no practical usage of searching a string for an empty string when it's always assumed to be at the first position.

Answer (score 3):

I'm puzzled why you think this behavior is incorrect. To the extent that asking *Does 'abc' contain ''?* even makes sense, the answer has to be "yes": All strings contain the empty string as a trivial case. So the answer to your "why is this happening" question is because it's the only sane thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

It is s correct imho. At least it is what I expect that empty string is part of any other string. But maybe this is a philosophical question. ASP does it so, so live with it. Practically speaking, if you need a different behavior write your own Method, InStrNotEmpty or something, which returns false on empty search string.

Comment: Mmh. I think I just don't get the point what is the problem with the behavior, if there is no problem in a practical sense.